# What are a list of board game environments for RL practice?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, environment, open-source

Recently OpenAI removes their board game environments. (It may be possible to install an older version to get access to them, but I haven’t downgraded).

Is there a list of repositories or resources of board game or similar environments that can be used to practice RL implementations? Things like checkers, chess, backgammon, or even grid world and mazes would be excellent.

A running list might be useful for many in this community.

Comment: Maintaining a list of resources would be useful, but it is not something the Stack Exchange Q&A format is good for. Some introductory material - such as textbooks on major AI topics - does end up as Q&A here (and often upvoted Q&A, which shows users appreciate it). But a minor topic like this is unlikely to attract a decent answer that will be maintained.